# Идентификатор на Node.js и Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Я заменю базу данных с Mysql на Mongodb и у меня проблема с корзиной

// запрос на Mysql

```
'SELECT id,name,cost FROM goods WHERE id IN ('+req.body.key.join(',')+')',
```

// что должно получиться на Mongo

```
app.post('/get-goods-info', function(req, res){
console.log(req.body.key);
if (req.body.key.length !=0) {
    const goods = mongoose.model("goods", GoodsSchema);
    goods.find({
        _id : {
            $in : new ObjectId("+req.body.key.join(',')+")
        }
    },function(error, result,fiels){
        if(error) throw error;
        let goods = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            goods[result[i]['_id']] = result[i];
        }
        res.json(goods)
    });
    } else {
        res.send('0')
    }
});
```

// Ajax запрос

```
  let cart = {}
      document.querySelectorAll(".add-to-cart").forEach(function(element){
       element.onclick = addToCart;
  });

  if(localStorage.getItem('cart')){
      cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
      ajaxGetGoodsInfo()
  }

  function addToCart(){
      let goodsId = this.dataset.goods_id;
      if(cart[goodsId]) {
          cart[goodsId]++;
     } else {
         cart[goodsId] = 1;
     }
       console.log(cart)
       ajaxGetGoodsInfo();
  }

  function ajaxGetGoodsInfo() {
     updateLocalStorageCart();
      fetch('/get-goods-info',{
       method: 'POST',
       body: JSON.stringify({key: Object.keys(cart)}),
       headers: {
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
}).then(function(response){
    return response.text()
}).then(function(body){
    console.log(body)
    showCart(JSON.parse(body));
})
}
```

// И вот что показывает

Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Вроде как проблема в это строке кода. Но я уже все перепробовал

```
        goods.find({
        _id : {
            $in : new ObjectId("+req.body.key.join(',')+")
        }
```

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, что `всё вы перепробовали`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
app.post('/get-goods-info', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.key || req.body.key.length === 0) {
    res.send('0');
  }

  const goods = mongoose.model('goods', GoodsSchema);
  const idx = req.body.key.map((x) => new ObjectId(x));
  goods.find(
    {
      _id: {
        $in: idx
      }
    },
    (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(err);
        throw error;
      }

      const goods = result.reduce(
        (acc, item) => {
          acc[item['_id']] = item;
          return acc;
        },
        {}
      );
      res.json(goods);
    }
  );
});
```